# Get all values of local variable value outside of function

Tags: python, variables, scope

```
      soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle, "html.parser")
      soup = soup.find('ul', class_='listing')
      thdr = soup.find('div', class_='heading')

      if (chk == "n"):
         
      while (thdr != None):
      for thdr in thdr:
         global prod      
         temp = thdr.string
         prod = thdr.string
         print prod
```

I need to print the value of **prod** ouside of this function and loop.
This variable **prod** has multiple values but I am getting only the last value when I print this outside of function even after marking it as global.

Comment: You need to make it a list and append to it.  You're overwriting it right now.

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible piece of code. This is syntactically flawed

Comment: Maybe you should use list etc. to store the value of each `prod`.

Comment: This isn't a function so its hard to know for sure, but perhaps you want to create a local variable `prod = []`, append values to it, and then return that list when the function is done. So, no global variable.

Comment: Maybe the line `for thdr in thdr:` in your code is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm not quite sure what the code in your question is doing, so I'll use the sample code below to answer your question.*

**Solution**

Using `yield` keyword. It is used to create a generator function. A type of function that is memory efficient and can be used like an iterator object.

**Sample Code**

```
def foo(num):
    while num < 10:
        num += 1
        yield num

for n in foo(0):
    print(n)
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array on top and append items to it in each iteration. And then, print it once with all the values.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle, "html.parser")
uls = soup.find('ul', class_='listing')
thdr = soup.find('div', class_='heading')
prod_items = []
if (chk == "n"):
    for item in thdr:
        prod = item.string
        prod_items.append(prod)
    print(prod_items)
```

Comment: Their code _already_ does the thing you're suggesting in your code example (printing it once per loop iteration).  The question is how to access all of them _outside_ of the loop.  The "Or you can also..." part is the only correct solution here.  The code example does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list(as others are saying) of `prod` under your `if` statement then keep appending it under the `for` loop and finally you can simply add a `print` statement after the loop is ended to print out the whole list of `prod`

you don't need to use `global` keyword

This is what I'm trying to say:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle, "html.parser")
soup = soup.find('ul', class_='listing')
thdrs = soup.find_all('div', class_='heading') 

if chk == "n":
    prods = [] 
    for thdr in thdrs: 
        prod = thdr.string
        prods.append(prod) 
        print(prod) 
    print(prods)
```